# Word meaning society ruled by Artificial General Intelligence?

Tags: single-word-requests, government

I remember reading a word once which had this meaning which starts with the letter 'a', like "agritocracy" or "autotocracy". I just can't remember the word now; it specifically means rule of a society by an artificial general intelligence. Mostly I'm creating this question for self-tracking. I already know such a word exists because I read it and looked up the meaning in the past. I just can't remember the word a few months later.

Comment: *Aristocracy*??

Comment: No that's rule by aristocrats.

Comment: To rule a human society, a ruler must be prepared to use force. If the force is exercised by machines against people, you have a **mechanical dystopia**. If the force is exercised by people more loyal to a machine than to their fellow humans, you have a **theocracy**, which you could qualify with **AI**.  An imagined human society that does not require the occasional use of force against its members is essentially a **fantasyland**.

Comment: What's the difference between an artificial intelligence and an artificial *general* intelligence?

Comment: @Decapitated Soul Perhaps some might need a few more question marks.

Comment: @nnnnnn I suggest you look it up on Wikipedia. These are two different terms with two different meanings. A chess AI is really good at chess. But it cannot drive a car. So it is an artificial intelligence but it is not an artificial general intelligence. The human brain, on the other hand, is an example of a general intelligence that is not artificial. Please keep the discussion on-topic and take off-topic questions to either our chat or Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word I was trying to recall is **algocracy**. I realize this isn't so much rule by AGI, but moreso society where law is executed as code, which could include an AI program, but might also include blockchain smart-contract-based legal systems.

I know this must be the word because I was ran into this term in a transhumanist forum originally, so this adds up.

I do like people's answer automatocracy though; that seems like a much better word to describe rule by AGI specifically.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, "automata" (the plural of automaton) is a theoretical branch of computer science that has played a major role in artificial intelligence. The word you are looking for, therefore, would be "Automatocracy".  See [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory)

Comment: An example of "automatocracy" being used in a sentence where it means "a government run by A.I." that I found is a writing prompt posted to Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/WritingPrompts/comments/4bt0qg/wp_we_now_live_in_a_democratic_automatocracy/

Answer (score 1):

Though the following word doesn't begin with the letter 'a', [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robotocracy) lists

> **robotocracy** (uncountable)
>
> rule by robots

The robots involved would obviously have to possess intelligence at some level; [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot)] licenses this (though the very existence of the word virtually demands it) here:

> Robots can be autonomous

And in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_robot):

> Autonomous robotics is usually considered to be a subfield of
> artificial intelligence, robotics, and information engineering

though of course outward appearance need not be humanoid.

The term **automatocracy** is mentioned (with the equivalent of scare quotes) in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3APolitical_ideas_in_science_fiction) on 'Political ideas in Science Fiction', but has a very limited circulation. Though it has been used outside the SF community; this [Reddit article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Automatocracy/) on politics uses the term. It is perhaps borderline acceptable, needing scare quotes outside SF at the moment.